# How to add bots in Half-life 2 deathmatch?

Tags: half-life-2, half-life-2-deathmatch

I have the latest free Steam version of Half-life 2 deathmatch. I have tried to add Hurricane Bot 1.1.3 and rcbot2 and didn't succeed.

When I type hrcbot_add or bot_add, or rcbot addbot, console respond with "unknown command" error.

I put downloaded dlls into ...steam/steamaps/username/half-life 2 deathmatch/hl2mp/addons

Comment: not sure but you may need to enable sv_cheats ?

Comment: and what's next?

Answer (score 1):

You have to go on that site and see the maps that take the bot location:

```
C:\Program Files\Half-Life 2 Deathmatch\hl2mp\addons\hrcbot_server_plugin
```